# Dumping MariaDB database with mysqldump encoding issues

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I am trying to dump mysql database as it would be exported from PhpMyAdmin (PA). I can see that I have an issue with encoding some values. Using MariaDb 10.5

PA output this: `0x00000000000000000000ffffd5065ccc`
Output from PA export:

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` VALUES
(1810, 2418, 1598915781.825139, 1, 'loginFailValidUsername', 'admin', 1, 0x00000000000000000000ffff556a967f, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36'),
```

When I run mysqldump from ssh terminal like this:

```sh
cdate=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S')
mysqldump -u dbusernamehere -p'secretpass' -h localhost --skip-opt mydatabasename > "v8_${cdate}-sitename.sql"
```

It continas this line instead: `\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0���\\�`
Output from mysqldump:

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` VALUES
(1810,2418,1598915781.825139,1,'loginFailValidUsername','admin',1,'\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0��Uj�','Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36');
```

--skip-opt

> disable the --opt option (disables --add-drop-table, --add-locks,
> --create-options, --quick, --extended-insert, --lock-tables, --set-charset, and --disable-keys).

[image: Using MariaDb 10.5 so it would be utf8mb4 as default]
I am using MariaDb 10.5 so it would be utf8mb4 as default,
MaraiDB mysqldump [Docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysqldump/)

Any idea what is missing?

Comment: please edit your question to show (as text, not an image) output of `show create table yourtablename` for the table having the problem, and some sample data that causes the problem?

Comment: what type of export are you doing in phpmyadmin?

Comment: @ysth just standard export data and structure. I am only concern about encoding at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

## Solved

I was about to delete this question as I found the answer, but it might help to someone else so:

```
--hex-blob
```

was missing from my flags

Now it outputs `0000000000000000000FFFF556A967F`:

```
INSERT INTO `sometable` VALUES
(1810,2418,1598915781.825139,1,'loginFailValidUsername','admin',1,0x00000000000000000000FFFF556A967F,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36');
```